# Clear whole DOM before page load from browser extension

Tags: javascript, dom, replace, browser

I am trying to write a browser extension which improves a website with very bad performance and countless unnecessary and duplicate network requests by replacing the content with a simpler version and doing the requests myself.

To do this I would like to replace/clear the whole DOM **before the content is loaded** and network requests are sent. So far I have tried multiple ways, but all of them only work when the content-script is set to `"run_at": "document_end"`. This way I can do something like

```
document.head.innerHTML = "";
document.body.innerHTML = "";
```

Because it only runs at `document_end`, it takes some seconds before the script is run and  there are still some network requests going out.

Is there any way to completely clear the DOM when loading a website, so that it my script can be run immediatly? When I try my scripts with `"run_at": "document_start` they don't work at all and the original page is loaded.

Comment: Random idea: `"run_at": "document_start`, wait for the bare essentials of what your script needs to run, then `window.stop()`?

Comment: *"I am trying to write a browser extension which improves a website..."* Good idea but what made you think your design goal is even possible? How do you plan to optimize client-side script code that could have an infinite number of patterns for your "solution" to jump in as the "middleware"?

Comment: There should be a SO standard answer to impossible design goals, but since there isn't, I'd suggest that you give up on this project immediately or perhaps, state your real intent.

Comment: @GetSet I don't plan on recreating the whole website, just make a simple version with some basic features which are enough for me/some of my friends, because we are annoyed by how slow this site is. It's just a fun project I wanted to try out.

Comment: Ahh I see @Nils well glad it worked out.